# Retrieve Object when checkbox value of table row changes

Tags: angular, typescript

In the following table, when I change the `status` by clicking on the `checkbox` control, I need to `console.log` the Course Id which is denoted here as `cId`. How can I do this ?

**HTML**

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

          <!-- Position Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="cId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Course Id </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cId}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          
          <!-- Name Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="courseTitle">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Course Title </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.courseTitle}} </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="courseStatus">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <div class="form-check form-switch">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" 
                      (change)="changeStatus($event)">
            </div>
           </td>
          </ng-container>
    </table>
```

**.TS**

```
changeStatus(event: any){
  console.log("Status "+ JSON.stringify(event.target.value));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a better way of doing this. You need to pass the element as shown in the code below.

```
      <ng-container matColumnDef="courseStatus">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <div class="form-check form-switch">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" 
                  (change)="changeStatus($event, element)">
        </div>
       </td>
      </ng-container>
```

.TS

```
changeStatus(event: any, element: any){
  console.log("Status "+ JSON.stringify(event.target.value));
  console.log("Status "+ JSON.stringify(element));

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something in ngOnChanges hook (I write this on top of my mind):

```
ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
    if (changes.element && changes.element.cId && changes.element.cId.currentValue && changes.element.cId.previousValue != changes.element.cId.currentValue) {
        console.log(changes.element.cId.currentValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: It says `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'cId' of undefined`

Comment: Sorry I edited it, needed to check for changes.element in the first place

Comment: I still am unable to read the value. Sorry but, I am a newbie. :(